# Odd Set Notation (Square Brackets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, arithmetic

I'm going through *Arithmetics in extensions of $\textbf Q$* and I've come across this notation a few times (i.e. $\textbf Z[i]$ or $\textbf Z[w]$).

"Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer and $p(x)$ be its minimal (monic) polynomial
$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i $$

Such that $p(\alpha) = 0$ and $a_i \in \textbf Z$ ($\textbf Z$ is the set of integers) and $a_n = 1$.

"The extension of a ring $A$ by the element $a$ is the set $A[\alpha]$ of all complex numbers of the form $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} c_j\alpha^j $$ such that $c_j \in A$, with all the operations inherited from $A$.

"The degree of the extension is the degree  of the polynomial."

I completely understand the 'algebraic integer' and the 'minimal polynomial' and the concept of set/ring extension, at least I think. My issue is mostly with the middle sentence; when it says 'all the complex numbers of form', but isn't there only one minimal polynomial so there's only one element in the set $A[\alpha]$? Is that single element basically just $p(\alpha) - x^n$ ? Or are the $c_j$ related to the $a_i$ at all? The same $n$ is mentioned twice. If not then why introduce $p(x)$ at all? And what is ring $A$? Is that an initially empty set? And what does 'all the operations inherited from $A$' mean? Honestly, I can't find an explanation online for the $A[\alpha]$ sort of notation or any of my other questions online?

P.S. I know that $\textbf Z[i]$ represents the Gaussian integers which kind of makes sense since but not entirely for the same reasons as mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $A$ is a ring such as $\Bbb Z$.  $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer such as $i$, whose minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$.  The extension $A[\alpha]$ has numbers of the form $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+...+c_{n-1}a^{n-1}$.  In the example with $\alpha=i,$ the elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$ have the form $c_0+c_1i$.  The $c_j$ are not related to the $a_i$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks that has clarified it a lot. Just a quick follow up. I understand that A is a ring, but what's in it (like Z has all the integers in it) since A doesn't seem to be defined? Is the minimal polynomial just there to show what the degree of the elements in A[a] should be (n-1) with respect to a? In your example, is assume you did c0 +c1i because the degree of the minimal polynomial of i was 2. And in your example, Gaussian integers are an extension of integers. But how is A[a] an extension of A if A isn't defined? Is it inital empty, making any other set an extension? Thanks btw

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry, the other post hadn't loaded yet

Comment: In an abstract definition, $A$ could be any ring.  It could have integers, matrices, or polynomials, for example.  A ring contains an additive identity element, so it's never empty

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you. I'm going to look into rings more, I think I'm mistaking them for sets too much. And sorry, I feel really stupid asking all of the questions. Again, thanks.

Comment: Yes, ring-theory might be a better tag for this question than elementary-set-theory; rings are basically sets that have addition and multiplication satisfying certain properties (associative, distributive, etc.)

Comment: Are you sure that where you saw $\mathbb Z[w]$ it was $w$ and not $\omega$ (lowercase omega)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.

$A$ is a ring such as $\Bbb Z$.

$\alpha$ is an algebraic integer such as $i$, whose minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$.

The extension $A[\alpha]$ has numbers of the form $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+...+c_{n-1}a^{n-1},$ with $c_j\in A$.

In the example with $\alpha=i,$ the elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$ have the form $c_0+c_1i$.

The $c_j$ are not related to the $a_i$.

Note that, if $\alpha$ is a root of an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial,

then $\alpha ^n$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, ..., \alpha^{n-1}$.

In the example with $\alpha=i$, $\alpha^2=-1(1)+0(\alpha)$.

That is why, in the sum for $p(x),$ the index goes up to $n$,

whereas in the sum for an element of $A[\alpha],$ the index goes up to $n-1$.

Operations inherited from $A$ means that when we add or multiply two elements of $A[\alpha]$,

say $(c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+...+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1})+(d_0+d_1\alpha+d_2\alpha^2+...+d_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}),$

the result is $(c_0+d_0)+(c_1+d_1)\alpha+(c_2+d_2)\alpha^2+...+(c_{n-1}+d_{n-1})\alpha^{n-1},$

where $c_j+d_j$ is computed in $A$.

And when we multiply $(c_0+c_1i)(d_0+d_1i),$

the result is $c_0d_0+(c_0d_1+c_1d_9)i+c_1d_1i^2=c_0d_0-c_1d_1+(c_0d_1+d_1c_0)i, $

where again products and sums of terms involving $c_j$ and $d_j$ are computed in $A$.

Comment: This is great, really clarifies it. Just quickly, is $c_j$ just any arbitrary integer/real number or a set of all of them? Or is it saying that regardless of what values they are, ring A[a] will always be an extension of ring A becuase for any value you could have $0(a^{n-1})+...0(a)+k$? But then 0 isn't necessarily an element of ring A. In your example, A={0,-1}, A[a]={-1} so far, A[a] would also have -i if you swapped around $c_0$ and $c_1$, but that's not an extension of A. Also, what does 'computed in A' mean? Does it mean ($c_j + d_j$) is also an element of A?

Comment: this is the link btw. The second definition section, https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=374&lmm=0

Comment: Yes, each $c_j$ is an element of $A$, and so is $c_j+d_j$; $A$ is contained in $A[\alpha]$; as I said in comments to your question, a ring $A$ always contains $0$; in my example, $A$ could be $\mathbb Z$ and $\alpha$ could be $i$ -- then elements of $A[\alpha]$ are $0, \pm1, \pm2, ..., \pm i, \pm 2i, ..., \pm 1 \pm i, \pm 1 \pm 2i, ..., \pm 2 \pm i, \pm 2 \pm 2i, ...$

Answer (score 2):

I just want to expand on "operations inherited from $A$." If the book only talks about infinite domains like $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ with the usual addition and multiplication, mentioning operation inheritance might be needlessly confusing.

Consider for example the finite ring $\mathbb Z_{10}$, consisting of only the integers 0 to 9. This would seem to have the usual addition and multiplication, since, for example, $1 + 1 = 1 \times 2 = 2$.

However, $7 + 7 = 7 \times 2$ but does not equal 14. Both of those operations "wrap around" to land back in $\mathbb Z_{10}$, giving 4 rather than 14 in this case.

Now consider $\mathbb Z_{10}[\sqrt{53}]$. Then $\sqrt{53} + \sqrt{53} = 2\sqrt{53}$ just like we expect. But $7 \times 2\sqrt{53}$ is not $14\sqrt{53}$ but $4\sqrt{53}$.

What would $(\sqrt{53})^2$ be? I'm not exactly sure, I myself am confused on this point. But hopefully I have given you a clearer understanding of how addition and multiplication might differ from what you're used to.

Rings of matrices might provide another good example.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is much more in the language I understand; I've only just finished sixth form (UK for year before university). So let me try and 100% get this straight. This example of $Z_10$ will probably help best. $Z_10={0,1,...,8,9}$. The minimal polynomial of $53^0.5$ is $x^2 - 53$, so the form of the additional elements in $Z_10[53^0.5]$ can be in the form of $c_0 + 53^0.5 c_1$ where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are any of the elements (integers) in 'ring' $Z_10$, in any order. So $Z_10[53^0.5]={0,1,...,8,9,53^0.5,2(53^0.5),...,9(53^0.5)}$. Sorry, I'm a bit new to the maths text.

Comment: Thats meant to be 53 to the power of 0.5, since I can't remember how to do the square root

Comment: Also, so that I don't take up too much of your time, could you point me in the direct of what I should look up to better understand this notation?

Comment: Over $\mathbb Z_{10},$ $\sqrt{53}^2=53\equiv3$

Comment: That would be `\sqrt{ab}` to get $\sqrt{ab}$. If you right-click, it should give you an option to see the TeX command